# Vue JS - Apply certain classes to elements in a v-for loop according to data from previous elements in the loop

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Sorry for the lengthy title, I have a feeling this is an oddly specific edge case not many people have to deal with.

Some background, I'm working on a webapp to track PC repairs for our shop. We have one currently, which we purchased and have access to the source code thanks to the author's method of distribution. Each repair is signified by a Work Order, all of which have notes. In the old app, the notes have the users name, the date it was posted, and the edit and delete buttons (if you are either the admin or the author) on the left, and the note on the right. If the user that posted the note changes when going down the list, it swaps them around, so the note is on the left and user is on the right, i.e.

```
user1 - note text
note text - user2
user3 - note text
user3 - note text
note text - user1
```

The old app did this with plain PHP, in a php file filled to the brim with echo statements. The new app I was working on has a laravel backend (to make use of things like Eloquent) with a Vue JS frontend (to assist with live updates in websockets). So on the Work Order page, there is a component for the list of notes, which takes the list of notes assigned to that Work Order as a prop, and iterates over all the notes with a v-for. I wanted to mimic the orientation switching feature from the previous setup. I can acheive the switch by setting up each note as a grid container, and applying either order-first or order-last to the column containing the user info. What I'm struggling with is trying to find a way to toggle which class is applied when the user changes.

At first I had a data attribute keeping track of the current class, so when the user changed I could check what the class was currently and switch it to the opposite. However, this caused an infinite render loop, as the entire list of notes would re-render whenever that attribute was changed. It did accomplish what I wanted to do visually, but it caused severe performance issues. Then I tried using refs, so when the user changed I could get the previous entry in the list from the refs array and examine its classes to see what order class it had to set the next elements order class appropriately. However this didn't work because the refs array would not be populated until the list was done rendering, and I needed to set the class as it rendered. I tried using a computed property, but it can't take arguments (i.e. the index of the array I was currently on to compare with index-1) and even if it could there is no way I could find to check the current cached value of that property while calculating the new one.

Here is the code I am working with for reference, currently with any of the previous approaches I tried removed, so currently no user switching happens.

```
 <template>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="row no-gutters mb-2" v-bind:key="index" v-for="(note, index) in this.notes">
            <note-form-modal :modal-id="'note'+note.noteid+'editModal'" :populate-with="note"></note-form-modal>
            <div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column mx-md-3">
                <div class="text-center p-0 m-0">{{note.noteuser}}</div>
                <div class="text-muted text-small text-center p-0 m-0">{{getHRDate(note.notetime)}}</div>
                <div class="btn-group justify-content-center p-0 m-0">
                    <template v-if="authusername === note.noteuser || authusername === 'admin'">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-1" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#note'+note.noteid+'editModal'"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger m-1"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="card m-2">
                    <div class="card-body p-2">
                        {{ note.thenote }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
import dateMixin from '../mixins/dateMixin'
export default {
    mixins:[dateMixin],
    props: ['initialnotes', 'authusername', 'noteType', 'woid'],
    data () {
        return {
            notes: Object.values(this.initialnotes),
            currentOrder: 'order-first',
            newNote: {
                notetype: this.noteType,
                thenote: '',
                noteuser: this.authusername,
                woid: this.woid
            }
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        Echo.channel('wonotes.'+this.noteType+'.'+this.woid)
            .listen('WorkOrderNoteAdded', (e) => {
                this.notes.push(e.note)
            })
            .listen('WorkOrderNoteEdited', (e) => {
                let index = this.notes.findIndex((note) => {
                    return note.noteid === e.note.noteid
                })
                this.notes[index] = e.note
            })
            .listen('WorkOrderNoteDeleted', (e) => {
                let index = this.notes.findIndex((note) => {
                    return note.noteid === e.noteid
                })
                this.notes.splice(index, 1)
            })
    },
    methods: {
        createNote () {
            axios.post('/api/workorders/notes', this.newNote)
                    .then((response) => {
                        $('#note'+this.noteType+'add').collapse('hide')
                        this.newNote.thenote = ''
                    })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

noteType is there because we have two different types of notes, one that a customer can see, and one that only techs can see.

Is there something obvious I'm missing, have I just architected this thing wrong, am I trying to do something impossible? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I'm at the end of my rope here with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution to this, not sure if its the best one but here goes.

Basically, I maintain an array parallel to the notes array that determines which `order-` class each array index should have. As it is dependent on the `notes` attribute, I make it a computed property, so that I can use the notes attribute and it automatically updates when the notes list changes. The file now looks like this (with some code related to posting new notes and editing existing ones removed for clarity)

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="row no-gutters mb-2" v-bind:key="index" v-for="(note, index) in this.notes">
            <div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column mx-md-3" :class="noteOrders[index]">
                <div class="text-center p-0 m-0">{{note.noteuser}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="card m-2">
                    <div class="card-body p-2">
                        {{ note.thenote }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['initialnotes'],
    data () {
        return {
            notes: this.initialnotes,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        noteOrders () {
            return this.getNoteOrders(this.notes)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getNoteOrders(notes) {
            let noteOrders = []
            notes.forEach((note,index) =>{
                if (index === 0) {
                    noteOrders[index] = 'order-first'
                } else if (note.noteuser !== notes[index-1].noteuser) {
                    if (noteOrders[index-1] === 'order-first') {
                        noteOrders[index] = 'order-last'
                    } else {
                        noteOrders[index] = 'order-first'
                    }
                } else {
                    noteOrders[index] = noteOrders[index-1]
                }
            })
            return noteOrders
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

There may very well be better solutions and I encourage anyone who happens upon this to post theirs if they have one, but as I found a solution that works for me I decided to post it for anyone else running into the same issue.